# MVC should I document controller functions

Tags: model-view-controller, controllers, phpdoc

I was wondering something. Usually when I make a function, I use PHPDoc to document the function. This to explain what the function does.

My question is, should I also document functions in a Codeigniter (or any MVC framework) controller? Like, the functions mainly are called by routing and are just to show a page, so I don't know if it's necessary to document it.

Answer (score 0):

Probably better if you did, as the PHPDoc's aren't only for you, but also for others that come after you. For them(and you) it would be easier to read which page the controller is for.

After using a documentor tool, there will be classes and methods without any code, including those which don't have any phpdoc. As there is no code on those pages, you'd be hardpresssed to discover which controller is for which page (though it might be apperant from the class name).